# Is my proof ok? Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that the congruence modulo $m$ relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ is transitive.

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-verification

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that the congruence modulo $m$ relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ is transitive.

If $A$ is congruent to $B$ mod $m$ 
then $A - B = k  m~~$ (1)

If $B$ is congruent to $C$ mod $m$ 
then $B - C = p  m~~$ (2)

(1) with (2): 
$A - C = m (k + p)$

Therefore $A$ is congruent to $C$ mod $m$.

Comment: That looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks I was just wondering if it needed more description.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I'd rewrite the first step more carefully:

Suppose that $A$ is congruent to $B$ mod $m$; then there's an integer $k$ such that $A - B = km$.

That is, I'd make the *existence* of the integer $k$ more clearly be related to divisibility. When you write $A - B = km$, the reader doesn't know what $k$ is, so the statement isn't really either true or false ... it's just nonsense. Yeah, we all write proofs like this all the time...but if you're at the stage of being worried about whether this proof is correct, then including all the quantifiers is probably a good idea.